# Grails Jquery-ui plugin configuration

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Trying to use the Jquery-UI plugin from http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui 
but apparently the documentations is not correct when discuss using the plugin with  resources framework as following the instructions leads to an error:

```
Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <r:layoutResources>: No module found with name [jquery-ui]
```

Apparently the same problem is known around, but was not able to find a solution on the net (example: [some discussion here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Jquery-ui-plugin-td4631682.html) and some other discussions with no solution or hints to a solution).

Did anyone managed to successfully configure jquery-ui in grails with the resource framework?

Comment: can you share the relevant parts of your GSP

Comment: <r:require module="jquery-ui" />
<g:layoutHead /> <br />and I confirm that the plugin is found in the plugins dir and it includes the correct module for jquery-ui.

Comment: Try this <r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
 <r:layoutResources/>.  What do you have in the Config.groovy section grails.resources.modules = { ... }?

Comment: <r:layoutResources/> is just a line below my <g:layoutHead />. And I do not have any grails.resources.modules on Config.groovy.
I do have configured some other modules in ApplicationResources.groovy and they work fine. I have also tested the r:require module="jquery-ui" on a new plain grails project and it does not work. Always fails with the same error.

Comment: For r:require module="jquery-ui" you need something like this (in Config.groovy) grails.resources.modules = {
    jquery-ui {
        dependsOn 'jquery-ui'
    } ... See http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/3.%20Declaring%20resources.html

Comment: Are you also using the Grails jQuery plugin?

Comment: @drorb yes of course :)

Comment: @Todd Murray I am gonna try and let you know

Comment: are you using the date picker? if so it requires adding its .js file as an additional resource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to install the plugin, so in your BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
  ...
  compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
  ...
}
```

Use `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` and see if the console output the download of the plugin. If you are using STS, you can go in `right click > grails tools > refresh dependencies`

After that, you can add `<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>` before the `<r:layoutResources/>`

A usefull tip is the change of the jquery ui theme, you can configure this in your `ApplicationResources.groovy`

```
modules = {
    overrides {
        'jquery-theme' {
            resource id:'theme', url:'/css/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css'
        }
    }
}
```

In this example i have one css located in `web-app/css/ui/`.

Another tip is that you can force your modules to depend on jquery-ui:

```
modules = {
  mymodule {
    dependsOn 'jquery-ui'
    resource url: '/js/my.js'
  }
}
```

So if you add the resource `mymodule` to your GSP, the `jquery-ui` will be loaded too.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently despite installing the plugin, it needs to be compiled in the BuildConfig which is not mentioned at http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui

Comment: @Al-Punk can you please help me with using jquery-ui to use date-picker.  I am using asset-pipeline